# pyspark concatenate multiple csv files in one

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I need to use function concat(Path trg, Path[] psrcs) from [org.apache.hadoop.fs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#concat-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path:A-) with pyspark

My code is:

```
orig1_fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(f'{tmp_path}{filename1}')
orig2_fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(f'{tmp_path}{filename2}')
dest_fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(dest_path)    
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
fs.concat(dest_fs, list((orig1_fs , orig2_fs)))
```

But I get error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNRo8.png)

How can I use the function?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the 2nd argument of `concat` method is an `Array` not an `ArrayList`

```py
# transform from `ArrayList<Path>` to `Path[]`
py_paths = [orig1_fs , orig2_fs]
java_paths = sc._gateway.new_array(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, len(py_paths))
for i in range(len(py_paths)):
    java_paths[i] = py_paths[i]

# you can use the new array now
fs.concat(dest_fs, java_paths)
```